# using hector_trajectory_server to show trajectory in Rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to show trajectory of the quadcopter simulated in gazebo using Rviz.

I have learned that ‘[hector_trajectory_server](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_trajectory_server)’ could be used to solve this problem, refer to this old [Q&A](https://answers.ros.org/question/213157/displaying-the-robots-actual-trajectory-in-rviz/).

Since i am totally new in this field, anyone could give me some guidance on how to use this node (or Tutorial on using this node)?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269975/using-hector_trajectory_server-to-show-trajectory-in-rviz/) by [peigong](https://answers.ros.org/users/31721/peigong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-08-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried on my launch file:

```
<node pkg="hector_trajectory_server" type="hector_trajectory_server" name="hector_trajectory_server" output="screen">
    <param name="target_frame_name" type="string" value="/map" />
    <param name="source_frame_name" type="string" value="/base_link" />
    <param name="trajectory_update_rate" type="double" value="4" />
    <param name="trajectory_publish_rate" type="double" value="0.25" />

</node>
```

But after running it, it does not show the "trajectory" topic to uses on RViz. Please, do you know if another package shall be included on launch file to enable trajectory (nav_msgs/Path) ?

---

Originally posted by [gubertoli](https://answers.ros.org/users/34045/gubertoli/) with karma: 36 on 2018-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-08-03**:
The frame names shouldn't have the slashes `/` in them, but that doesn't appear to mess up the trajectory.  By default it should publish on the `trajectory` topic, you have to add the Path in rviz to see it.